# Can't clone Bitbucket repo via https

Tags: mercurial, https, bitbucket

Can't clone Bitbucket repo via https on Debian. I always get error:

**abort: authorization failed**

Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.4.1), Python 2.5.2

Thru ssh and http(w/o pass) work fine.

Comment: what do you see when you run with --debug ?

Answer (score 1):

After updating my own password on Bitbucket all works fine

Comment: strange, had the exact same issue!